# How to replace letter with special characters in beginning?

Tags: java

I want to replace the vowel with spacial character at the beginning of consonant
can anybody help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Replace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=in.nextLine();
        String str=s.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","*");
        String res=str.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(res);

    }

}
```

```
Input-tour
Output-*t*r (Output must be in lowercase)
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "...at the beginning of consonant?" What you have there should replace all vowels, regardless of case, with an asterisk, so describe fully where that course of action should not take place. The better you describe your problem and requirements, the better an answer you will receive.

Comment: my code will return `t**r` i want  `*t*r`

Comment: So you're saying that you want an asterisk preceding the first character if it's a consonant, and an asterisk for any sequence of one or more vowels? Again, you need to describe what you want. I shouldn't have to be asking you these questions to clarify what you should be writing in the first place.

Comment: `String str = s.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]+", "\\*");` should do it. You can prepend an asterisk if you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture all the consonants preceding the vowel, so you can insert the `*` before them.

```java
String s = "tour  Incomprehensibilities";
s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("([a-z&&[^aeiou]]*)[aeiou]","*$1");
System.out.println(s); // *t*r  **nc*mpr*h*ns*b*l*t*s
```